Python - Concurrent file seek and write
I'm making a concurrent file downloader, which downloads in segment files and merges them afterwards. I want to improve it by pre-creating a big file with the whole size, then each thread will seek its corresponding start offset and write.
I've googled and tried different ways. None of them worked.
Simplified code:
from random import shuffle
from threading import Lock, Thread

lock = Lock()

def writer(i):
    with lock:
        with open("2.txt", "wb") as f:
            f.seek(i)
            f.write(f"{i}".encode("utf-8"))
            f.flush()

def test():
    # Pre-create the file
    with open("2.txt", "wb") as f:
        f.seek(7)
        f.write(b"\0")
        f.flush()

    # Spawn and execute the threads in randomized order
    # to mimic the concurrent downloader
    threads = [Thread(target = writer, args = (i, )) for i in range(8)]
    shuffle(threads)
    [t.start() for t in threads]
    [t.join() for t in threads]
    # Read the result
    with open("2.txt", "rb") as f:
        print(f.read())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for _ in range(5):
        test()

This code writes the file with "wb" in the writer function, and gives this result:
[pairman@pairface bw]$ python test.py 
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x005'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x005'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x007'
b'\x00\x002'
b'\x001'

As seen, "wb" overwrites the file if existing, not satisfying my need. If I change "wb" to "ab", the seek won't work and the writer threads just append in random order:
[pairman@pairface bw]$ python test.py 
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0062045173'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0073502146'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0005432716'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0024036751'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0052046317'

So is there any way to open, seek and write to a file truly concurrently?

There is no need to pre-create the file with content because you can seek and write beyond the current length of a file. The file will be extended and filled (where necessary) with binary zero

There is no need to pre-create the file with content because you can seek and write beyond the current length of a file. The file will be extended and filled (where necessary) with binary zero.
Your calls to flush() are unnecessary.
Rather than shuffling a list of threads, just randomize the values in a range.
from random import sample
from threading import Lock, Thread
from pathlib import Path

def execute(i: int, lock: Lock, file: Path) -> None:
    with lock:
        with file.open("rb+") as data:
            data.seek(i)
            data.write(i.to_bytes())

def main(file: Path, nthreads: int) -> None:
    assert nthreads <= 256
    with file.open("wb"):
        pass

    lock = Lock()
    threads = []

    for i in sample(range(nthreads), nthreads):
        thread = Thread(target=execute, args=(i, lock, file))
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    with file.open("rb") as data:
        content = data.read()
        print(*map(int, content))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # cannot be more than 256 because of the way the output file is written
    nthreads = 10 
    main(Path("foo.bin"), nthreads)

Output:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9


Thanks! I played around and found out that the Lock isn't really useful too. On my system (Linux) only one thread is really writing to the file at a time. Without the lock the order is still correct. Maybe the underlying syscall took care for the lock

@Pairman Your assertion that the lock is unnecessary seems to be correct (also on MacOS) even when nthreads is 256. I've been trying to figure out why that would be the case. It seems counter-intuitive to me. Perhaps someone else can explain

Solved - use "rb+" to seek and write concurrently.
